# How does JSTileMap handle retina and ipad/iphone tile maps?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, retina-display, sprite-kit

I have created a basic tilemap using Tiled.  I am using JSTileMap with SpriteKit to get the map in the scene.  As I understood, JSTileMap (rather SKTexture) handles the retina and different devices automatically.  I have not been able to produce good results so far, here is my setup:

I have one .tmx file created at a base resolution using map.png as it's tile set.  The .tmx is present in the project but I purposely did not add map.png (I do not want to support non-retina iPhones).

In the project I only added the following .png's:
map@2x~iphone.png (retina iPhones, using 48x48 tiles)
map~ipad.png (non-retina iPads, using 48x48 tiles)
map@2x~ipad.png (retina iPads, using 96x96 tiles)

Here are the results I get (after clean builds and reset content and settings on simulator):

Retina iPhone - tiles is wrong spots
iPad - no tilemap displayed, JSTileMap has parsing error
Retina iPad - tiles in wrong spots

If I use just a plain vanilla map.png (with 48x48 tiles):
Retina iPhone - tile map displays well but too large of course
iPad - tile map displays perfectly
Retina iPad - tile map display perfectly and is scaled.

I know I could just use a 24x24 tile map.png and apparently it will scale everything. I would prefer not to use scaled tile sets as the quality would suffer.

Thanks in advance.

E

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to narrow down that SKTexture ignores the ~ipad file extension for the @2x file extension.  This only created more headaches in trying to build a tile map system for iPhone retina, iPad, and iPad retina.

I have decided to avoid the problem all together.  I am not using a universal app in my project now.  I have a iPhone project and a separate iPad Project.  This way all I need to do to work with Retina is the @2x file extension in each project.

This does fully work (much easier).  A word to the wise to those only building for retina iPhones... half your tile height and width sizes in the .tmx files, otherwise you will have a great time trying to deal with the content scaling.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Sprite Kit and that requires iOS 7 there's actually no non-Retina iPhone to target anyway.

The thing in that instance is that you can't use @2x suffixed images without providing the same image without the @2x suffix. So the solution may be as simple as supplying the Retina iPhone images without the @2x suffix. You likely don't even need the ~iphone suffix either because the other two types of assets will only be used by the iPad devices.

This is based on an answer to a different question. I haven't personally verified it.

Comment: First, Thanks for the look Steffen.  Yes I have tried just about every permutation looking for the 'right' trick.  I am more looking or how it happens to try to figure out why it is still not right.  In your suggested fix, all builds use the default tile map (e.g. map.png) and ignore the iPad and iPad retina copies.  I have verified by placing a marker on each tile set to verify which tile set is being used.  It also scales the default on the iPhone retina to what I am guessing is 2x so only about half the map is visible.  Thanks again.

Comment: have you considered that the scene's scale mode may influence this behavior?

Comment: Yes, but still doesn't explain why JSTileMap (or SKTexture?) is not using the @2x~ipad file extensions, the only map being loaded is the default map.png.

Comment: Try loading a simple SKTexture with the image and check the texture's size. That way you know whether the problem is with the tilemap or SKTexture.

Comment: I have decided to avoid the problem all together.  Will use answer below to help people experiencing similar problems.